# How to authenticate Google Cloud Speech-To-Text client in PHP application?

Tags: php, google-authentication, google-speech-api, google-speech-to-text-api

For authentication Cloud Speech-To-Text  client in PHP application I use the following:

```
 $credentials = 'C:\cred.json';
 $client=new SpeechClient(['credentials'=>json_decode(file_get_contents($credentials), true)]);
```

For some reasons I receive error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client
> error: `POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
> {"error":"invalid_scope","error_description":"Invalid OAuth scope or
> ID token audience provided."}

The above method of authentication works perfectly in Text-To-Speech API.

```
$credentials = 'C:\cred.json';
$client = new TextToSpeechClient(['credentials' => json_decode(file_get_contents($credentials), true)]);
```

What is wrong/missing?

Comment: I ran into the same problem, but in my case is opposite. Speech-To-Text is working like a charm but Text-To-Speech produces the error you mentioned. Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 5):

The problem solved by updating Auth module (in Vendor folder). Just change your Auth version to the latest version in your composer.json file.

```
{
    "require": {
        "google/auth": "1.14.3",
        "google/cloud-text-to-speech": "^0.5.0",
        "google/cloud-speech": "^1.3",
        "google/protobuf": "^3.14",
        "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^6.1",
        "google/apiclient": "2.5"
    }
}
```

Once it's done, I just run

> composer update

in your command line in the appropriate directory. Now it works.

Comment: This saved my day!
I rather not add sub-dependencies to my composer or run `composer update` which would update all other libraries as well.

Running `composer update google/cloud-text-to-speech --with-dependencies` worked fine as well. Alternatively you could run `composer show` and check which dependencies you may need updating (in my case it worked if I updated "google/auth","google/gax" and "google/cloud-core")

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to outline the suggest of [@KevinDriessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1370000/kevin-driessen) in the comment because solve the problem (I got the same issue) without a general update of the vendor directory, that is not always desiderable.

```sh
composer update google/cloud-text-to-speech --with-dependencies
```